# what's difference between the 'git apply' and 'git fetch'?

Tags: git, gerrit

when I pull patch from gerrit，a question come:
what's difference between the 'git apply' and 'git fetch'?

```
cp patch /the/path/save
git apply patch
```

and

```
git fetch ssh://someone@gerrit.(SOME INFOMATION)  && git cherry-pick FETCH_HEAD
```

Are they the same thing? or do a first and then b

a,b can‘t be done at the same time.It seems that they do the same thing,but I still cannot understand what difference between them.

Comment: Uh, they do different things?

Comment: apply is used when you want to _apply_ a patch (a diff file, say) that you have on top of where you are working (the working tree or the index). `git fetch` gets information about branches and tags from a remote (repo). It does _not_ mess up with your local branches.

Comment: The documentation of [`git apply`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply) and [`git fetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) is a good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if fed the same commit contents, the result will differ:

- `git cherry-pick` will create a commit that's a copy of the specified commit and retain the original commit information (author, author-date, commit message)
- `git apply` will read a diff/patch file and apply it to your current working directory.
  It will **not** create a commit and if you do commit the resulting changes, the original commit information will **not** be in that commit.
  (Unless you manually add it yourself)

However, there's also `git am -k` which you can use to import a patch created by `git format-patch -k`. Then you should end up with a commit that's a copy of a commit, similar to cherry-picking.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-am
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch